# Shortcut link to another Stack Exchange site

Tags: support

What's the shortcut syntax to link to another Stack Exchange site? I can't remember and it's not in the help center! But I know it's worked before.

Answer (score 4):

The general form is `[sitename.se]` where `sitename` is the part of the fully qualified domain name preceding `stackexchange.com`. For example, `[worldbuilding.se]` or `[biology.se]` or `[meta.space.se]`.

Some sites have special "magic links", like `[so]` (Stack Overflow), `[sf]` (Server Fault) and so on.

You can also use links like `[meta]` and `[main]` to link back and forth between a single site's meta site and main site.

There's more; see [Add data.SE style “magic links” to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/157730) for a (hopefully current) list.

Note that these magic links only work in comments. In questions and answers, use the full form.

Comment: It might also be worth nothing that some sites have redirects. For example, Space Exploration also has the domain name `thefinalfrontier.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me.  I tried [physics.se] in an [Answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28740/how-can-species-pass-on-their-genes-to-the-next-generation-quantum-mechanically) (full form, not a magic abbreviation) and it doesn't take.  I see it working in this comment, though.

Comment: @JDługosz, you should probably re-read the very last line of the answer :)

Comment: last line:  magic links (e.g. `[so]`) only work in comments; answers need full (general) form (e.g. `[stackoverflow.se]`).